# Parent class private property is accessible from child class

Tags: php, class, oop

```
<?php
class Parent_Class
{
    //Properties defined
    private $name = "Faizan";
    //Constructor defined
    public function __construct () {
            echo 'The class "',__CLASS__.'" initialized <br>';
        }
    //Methods defined
    public function setName ($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }
    public function getName () {
            return $this->name;
        }
    // __toString() Method
    public function __toString () {
            return "<b>".__CLASS__."</b> toString magic method called <br>";
        }
    //Destructor defined
    public function __destruct () {
            echo 'The class "', __CLASS__,'" destroyed <br>';
        }
}
class Child_Class extends Parent_Class
{
    //Parent property override
    //private $name = "Abdullah";
    //Child class constructor override
    public function __construct () {
            parent::__construct();
            echo 'This is the <b>"', __CLASS__, '"</b> constructor. <br>';
        }
    //Child class __toString() override
    public function __toString () {
            parent::__toString();
            return "<b> ". __CLASS__ . "</b> toString() method <br>";
        }
    //Parent methods in class override
    public function setName ($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }
    public function getName () {
            return $this->name. " " .parent::getName();
        }
    //Child class destructor override
    public function __destruct() {
            parent::__destruct();
            echo 'The is the <b>"', __CLASS__, '"</b> destructor. <br>';
        }
}
$pObj = new Parent_Class;
echo $pObj->getName()."<br>";
$obj = new Child_Class;
echo $obj;  
echo $obj->getName(),"<br>";
//unset($obj);
$obj->setName("Ali");   
echo $obj->getName(), "<br>";
echo $pObj->getName()."<br>";       
?>
```

Comment: The child class only ever accesses name in the parent by calling the parent::getName(), it doesn't access it directly.... and the only time it tries it gets `Notice: Undefined property: Child_Class::$name`

Comment: So where do you think the parent's private name property is directly accessible from the child class?

Comment: Mr Mark Barker thanks for the answer. Problem solved.

Comment: Mr Barker I actually didn't find any error in my php output untill I close and relaunched browser then I found the bug: Notice: Undefined property: Child_Class::$name in E:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\student\test.php on line 50.